# What is wrong with this git smudge/clean filter?

Tags: git, filter, sed, gitattributes

I want to apply this filter in my git repository to remove a section from a solution file during checkout and to add this section during commit.

This is the section i want to remove or add:

```
GlobalSection(SubversionScc) = preSolution
    Svn-Managed = True
    Manager = AnkhSVN - Subversion Support for Visual Studio
EndGlobalSection
```

I have setup this filter in my .git/info/attributes

> *.sln  filter=SourceControlProvider

and i have added these commands to my config

```
$ git config filter.SourceControlProvider.smudge "sed -e '/GlobalSection(SubversionScc)/,/EndGlobalSection/d' %"
$ git config filter.SourceControlProvider.clean "sed -n -e '/^Global$/ r ankhsvnsection ' < %"
```

Well, it does not work. What have i done wrong?

ankhsvnsection is a text file that lies in the same directory as the *.sln file

Comment: Did you check if a simpler sed was working? Or is it an issue with sed being not found at execution time?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I see a few issues here:

1. You have `%` at the end of both filters.
   This has no special meaning and will be passed as an extra argument to *sed*, which will probably generate an error (unless you have a file named `%`).
   Filters should be “streaming” (read from stdin and write to stdout). Their definition can include `%f`, but it should not really be treated as a file to read or write; Git does that part, filters should just read from stdin and write to stdout.
2. Your clean filter tries to redirect stdin from `%f`.
   The input data will already be on stdin, there is no need to redirect.
3. The *sed* program in the clean filter uses the `r` command to access another file.
   Filters seem to be run from root of the working tree, but I am not sure if that is guaranteed.
4. The *sed* command in the clean filter uses `-n`. Its only output will be the contents of the `ankhsvnsection` file (assuming the input has a `Global` line).
5. Some versions of *sed* (at least the (old) BSD version in Mac OS X) do not allow whitespace after the filename of the `r` command (i.e. the space after `ankhsvnsection` in the clean filter’s *sed* program).

After adding, changing, or removing a filter you will probably need to *touch*, modify, or delete your working tree files before Git will apply the filter. Git’s index records the modification time of working tree files; if they have not changed, then Git will translate `git checkout -- file` and `git add file` into a no-op.

If you want to see the actual contents of the index (e.g. to check what the clean filter produced), you can use `git show :0:path/from/repo/root/to/file`. You can not usually use `git diff` for this since it also applies the filters.

These worked for me:

```
git config filter.SourceControlProvider.smudge "sed -e '/GlobalSection(SubversionScc)/,/EndGlobalSection/d'"
git config filter.SourceControlProvider.clean "sed -e '/^Global\$/ r ankhsvnsection'"
```

Comment: +1 for posting working lines. The rest includes some nitpicks or long shots (*some seds might not like the space after the filename*? c'mon... no sed is ever going to even receive the space unless quoted?)

Comment: @sehe: My *sed* complained about the program used in the question’s clean filter: `sed: 1: "/^Global\$/ r ankhsvnse ...": whitespace after read command`. The only “long shot” is the warning about the filter’s cwd; everything else was required to get the filters working properly (on my system, anyway).

Comment: I now get it. The filename you refer to was the operand to the 'r' command. Yes you cannot follow that by a space. Point taken.

Comment: (Edited the last point to clarify which space was an issue and on which platform.)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just tested the clean filter and it works great.