# How to set Git to ignore the word "xdebug_break()" for all project files?

Tags: git, xdebug, gitignore

I use NetBeans  as editor and Xdebug as PHP debug tool.
Is there a way to make Git to ignore all "xdebug_break()" words?
I am using windows 7.

Comment: *Is there a way to make Git to ignore all "xdebug_break()" words?* What do you mean by that? Could you clarify?

Comment: you have the file .gitignore. You can write insite it myfolder/ and Git will ignore this folder and every file inside it. I would like to know how to ignore a word "xdebug_break()" that can be inside my php code. I use this function to jump between lines of the code.

Comment: I can understand Git ignoring a *file*, but not Git ignoring a *word* in a file. Be more specific.

Comment: I use a lot of xdebug_break() to jump between lines of the code. Once the feature is good I must return and erase all lines otherwise Git will recognise as Changes. But it is not important to the code. I was just wondering if is it possible to cofigure the .gitignore to ignore all these words "xdebug_break()". Inside Assembla.com there is a option to make git ignore new empty lines. I was wondering some like this.

Comment: `.gitignore` is only meant for ignoring *paths*, not parts of a file. The answer to your question is "no".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you might want to use a "clean" filter to remove some code from some files automatically.  See [this stackoverflow posting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5380634/1256452) on setting up smudge and clean filters, and [this chapter of the Git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes).

My general rule of thumb on smudge and clean filters is: avoid them if at all possible; whatever you're doing needs to add a *lot* of value to make up for their cost (not just cpu-time, but also the "cognitive cost" of the fact that what you see when you edit and commit is not necessarily what you get when you check the file out again later).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can actually change the content of your files, but you could use a pre-commit hook to scan for instances of the string and cancel the commit if any are found.

http://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks